# Get records from dictionary pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have created a dictionnary CODE_di having 2 columns « Code1 » « Code2 » and I would like to map values contained on« Code2 » to an existing DataFrame ‘frame’

```
CODE_di = [{'PF5684' : 5643, 'KT6853':3457,....}]
CODE_di = frame_Code.set_index('Code1').T.to_dict('records')
frame['Code2']= frame ['Code1'].map(CODE_di)
```

When I map I got this error don't get why it doesn't work.

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['AZER424','GFDG5345','DG6546'],'col2':[1234,467,1347]})
dict_test = df.set_index('col1').T.to_dict('records')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col3':['AZER424','DG6546']})
df1['code']= df1['col3'].map(dict_test)
```

P.S: when I replace 'records' by 'list' or 'series' it works fine but I need only the records

Comment: Please try posting an example we can validate! A snippet that doesn't require adding more data.

Comment: I've edited my post and added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the dict you need to apply .to_dict() on a series. Do that by choosing which column, `col2` in this case, after set_index.

```
dict_test = df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict()
```

This works because:

```
type(df.set_index('col1')['col2']) == 'pandas.core.series.Series'
```